sftp is it possible to login linux as userA, then connect to sftp server in same machine as user sftp_user, using public/private key without password
I have setup an sftp server in my own linux and want to login this sftp server in my own linux, that is client and server under the same machine. I login my linux with user userA and create a sftp user with name sftp_user and group sftp.
then how to run an application in my linux with userA as login user, but in that application connect the sftp server in my own linux as user sftp_user:sftp using public/private key without password?
If I login using userA and use
ssh-keygen -t rsa

then copy the content of id_rsa.pub to my linux /home/sftp_user/.ssh/authorized_keys, it fails.
Should I keep using userA to connect the sftp if I login the linux as userA, don't use another user sftp_user to login my sftp server in same linux?
I am a novice in Linux, sorry if the question is not clear.

What command did you use to connect? What was the error message? Does login to sftp_user work when using password or does it fail too?

sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa sftp_user@127.0.0.1 but return sftp_user@127.0.0.1:Permission denied(publickey).
Finally I give up to login sftp as sftp_user but use userA as both linux login user and sftp login user, then can login without password.

The -i parameter with the path to key should not be needed, because if a SSH key is set up, SSH will try to use it before attempting password auth (unless disabled in configuration). I tried to replicate what you described on my computer and it works for me, I can login using sftp test@localhost without a password while being logged in as user raj. Maybe the permissions on authorized_keys file under sftp_user are wrong? It may help if you run sftp with -v parameter, it will then show what it is trying to use.

you gen the key "ssh-keygen -t rsa" using login user raj? then the private key is kept in your /home/rsa/.ssh/ and the public key content is copied to /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys?

The key for user raj has been generated long ago, even on another machine, since I use it for years and move from computer to computer. Now I created a new user test and copied /home/raj/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys. After this, sftp test@localhost from user raj works without password.
As I have mentioned previously, check permissions on your /home/sftp_user/.ssh/authorized_keys file, also try to run sftp with -v parameter to get more debugging information.
